# mpd stopped working under systemd, works when run on the command line

Tags: systemd, alsa, mpd

Yesterday my mpd stopped working. It has worked for several months until now, but when choosing music in `ncmpcpp` no sound would be output.

Today I tried stopping mpd:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop mpd
$ sudo systemctl stop mpd.socket
```

Then I tried running it interactively on the command line:

```
$ sudo mpd -v --no-daemon --stdout
```

When I re-ran `ncmpcpp` this worked; music could be played. I have no mpd conf files in my home folder so I think it should be using the same conf file (`/etc/mpd.conf`) as systemd.

So then I looked into the log files. They show:

```
Jun 14 10:06 : player: played "Orbital/The Middle Of Nowhere/01-Way Out -_.mp3"
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Jun 14 10:06 : alsa_output: Failed to open "My ALSA Device" [alsa]: Failed to open ALSA device "default": Device or resource busy
Jun 14 10:06 : output: Failed to open audio output
Jun 14 10:06 : player: problems opening audio device while playing "Orbital/The Middle Of Nowhere/01-Way Out -_.mp3"
```

It looks like some sort of ALSA problem but...

1. Why does it only affect me when running with systemd?
2. Why has it only just started being a problem (I don't think I've updated my system...)

I tried listing any other users of the sound devices:

```
$ lsof /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pulseaudi 3992 gravelld  mem    CHR  116,3           460 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
pulseaudi 3992 gravelld   16u   CHR  116,8      0t0  521 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi 3992 gravelld   23u   CHR  116,8      0t0  521 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi 3992 gravelld   24u   CHR  116,2      0t0  459 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 3992 gravelld   31u   CHR  116,2      0t0  459 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 3992 gravelld   36u   CHR  116,2      0t0  459 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 3992 gravelld   42u   CHR 116,17      0t0  576 /dev/snd/controlC2
pulseaudi 3992 gravelld   52u   CHR  116,2      0t0  459 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 3992 gravelld   58u   CHR  116,3      0t0  460 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
```

(`gravelld` is my user - the same one I can successfully run mpd on the command line from).

Comment: I'd guess that the sound device or, more likely, the dmix shared memory permissions are set so that different users are not allowed to share them. "Device or resource busy" means that some other program is already playing something.

Comment: But it works after ensuring it's stopped from systemctl then restarting from the command line. Can you provide any commands to list other programs playing something?

Comment: Try `lsof /dev/snd/*`.

Comment: Thanks, I added that detail. I wondered whether my user is grabbing the sound devices and stopping mpd, run from systemd, using them?